# How to do "new Class" with ClassName being a string?

Tags: java, string, class, arraylist

So I'm making an mini game and want to randomly get a new arena when the game restarts.
Each arena is a Java Class as data on each arena is changed and as i load and unload the map.

As i then in an `ArrayList<String>` and need to do `new Class` each time.
The reason why its string is because i dont want the class to be instanced before as the loader is in the constructor for each map

Ive tried looking into using the `class.forName()` function with then applying `newInstance()` does not seem to help.

```java
public class Arena {

    private ArrayList<String> maps;
    private Class currentMap;

    public Arena() {
        setMaps();
        setNewMap();
    }

    private void setMaps() {
        maps = new ArrayList<String>() {
            {
                add("Beach");
                add("CandyLand");
                add("Forest");
                add("Frozen");
                add("Space");
            }
        };
    }

    private void setNewMap() {
        Random rand = new Random();
        int n = rand.nextInt(4); // count includes 0

        try {
            currentMap = (Class) Class.forName(this.maps.get(n)).newInstance();
        } catch (IllegalAccessException | ClassNotFoundException | InstantiationException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public Class getCurrentMap() {
        return currentMap;
    }

    public ArrayList<String> getMaps() {
        return maps;
    }
}
```

I'm hoping to get the result of the same function as `new Class` does. Just by getting the Class from an array.

Comment: “Ive tried looking into using the class.forName() function with then applying newInstance() does not seem to help.” – how deeply did you look? Because that is exactly the way to go.

Comment: First of all: why are your different maps different classes? Shouldn't they just have different attributes but belong to the same class?

Comment: *The reason why its string is because i dont want the class to be instanced before as the loader is in the constructor for each map* ... that doesnt make any sense. Loading the class doesnt invoke any constructor. Your first instance gets build when you call `new X()` the first time. Seriously: you only use reflection when you absolutely have to. And for a person who seem to rather have started with Java, reflection is really not recommended.

Comment: Just to echo GhostCat's comment: [(Reflection) is a relatively advanced feature and should be used only by developers who have a strong grasp of the fundamentals of the language](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/reflect/index.html)

Comment: @GhostCat well the way is that when the class is called it loads the map until a function tells it to unload it like `getServer().createWorld(new WorldCreator("CandyLand"));` and the reason not to call every class is to spare loading.

Comment: Another thing is that i want to access the class function inside the map but it seems i cant

Comment: What is the error you are getting when you use newInstance or why newInstance is not helpful?

Comment: @SujayMohan i have functions inside the map class i cant seem to access like `game.getArena().getCurrentMap().getSpawns()` as getspawns is giving not reachable

Comment: @MeickiJeldal in that case you can check your instance type using  instanceof and type cast with your own class. It would be better if you use Factory pattern rather than reflection.

Comment: @SujayMohan this is where we get to a point i dont know about and have to look into it but thanks anyway

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Class.forName(this.maps.get(n)).newInstance()` is just fine. Of course you shouldn’t cast that to `Class`, because they are not instances of `Class`. Do your classes have a common base class? Then that’s the class to cast to.

You do not use fully qualified names. Perhaps you should.

Answer (score 0):

## Easy way

I suspect you are making your work much too complicated.

With the new `switch` statement abilities previewed in Java 13, you could simply do this.

```
int i = ThreadLocalRandom.current().nextInt( 1 , 6 ); // Half-open: origin is inclusive while the bound is exclusive.
Arena arena = switch ( i )
        {
            case 1 -> new Beach();
            case 2 -> new CandyLand();
            case 3 -> new Forest();
            case 4 -> new Frozen();
            case 5 -> new Space();
            default -> null;
        };

System.out.println( "BASIL - Done." );
```

Just 2 lines of code (kinda-sorta). And no wrangling of `Class` class and reflection.

By the way, your statement:

> The reason why its string is because i dont want the class to be instanced before as the loader is in the constructor for each map

…makes no sense to me. I suspect you are trying to avoid a problem that does not exist.

## Hard way

Nevertheless, you asked about wrestling with `Class`, so here goes.

I would avoid the strings. Using strings here adds no value. You know the specific set of classes that will be instantiated. So make a `List` of them, a [`List`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/List.html) that holds [`Class`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Class.html) objects. We can randomly pick one of these `Class` objects to instantiate an object of that type.

### Define a package

Place your classes in a package. I will use a package named `arena`. Import that package.

```
import work.basil.example.arena.* ;
```

### Define an interface `Arena`

Create an interface `Arena`, of which all five classes will implement.

```
package work.basil.example.arena;

public interface Arena
{
}
```

### Implement interface in each class

Each of our five `Arena`-implementing classes look like this. We will know the constructor ran successfully when we see the console output.

```
package work.basil.example.arena;

public class Beach implements Arena
{
    public Beach ( )
    {
        System.out.println( "BASIL - Constructing Beach. " );
    }
}
```

### Make list of classes

Make a `List` that holds `Class` objects, each representing the class used in your game app. The [`List.of`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/List.html#of(E,E,E,E,E)) syntax in Java 9 and later makes this simple, producing an [unmodifiable list](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/List.html#unmodifiable).

```
List < Class > classes = List.of( Beach.class , CandyLand.class , Forest.class , Frozen.class , Space.class );
```

### Randomly pick a class from list

Randomly pick one using [`ThreadLocalRandom::nextInt`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/concurrent/ThreadLocalRandom.html#nextInt(int,int)). Notice how we can declare the chosen class to be an `Arena`, by using parameterized type `< Arena >`.

```
int index = ThreadLocalRandom.current().nextInt(0 , classes.size()); // Half-open: origin is inclusive while the bound is exclusive.
Class < Arena > c = classes.get( index );
```

### Instantiate, but `Class::newInstance` deprecated

Instantiate an object from our randomly chosen class.

Note that the method you used [`Class::newInstance`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Class.html#newInstance()) is deprecated. The Javadoc instead recommends using [`clazz.getDeclaredConstructor().newInstance()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Class.html#getDeclaredConstructor(java.lang.Class...)).

Catch the various possible exceptions.

```
Arena arena = null;
try
{
    arena = c.getDeclaredConstructor().newInstance();
} catch ( InstantiationException e )
{
    e.printStackTrace();
} catch ( IllegalAccessException e )
{
    e.printStackTrace();
} catch ( InvocationTargetException e )
{
    e.printStackTrace();
} catch ( NoSuchMethodException e )
{
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Signal the end.

```
System.out.println( "BASIL - Done." );
```

See similar [code run live at IdeOne.com](https://ideone.com/hMbciH).

> BASIL - Constructing Forest.
>
> BASIL - Done.

Comment: I like what you’re writing here. I usually avoid to tell people that that they are asking the wrong question. Your answer does not really answer the question, but this time, the OP probably really didn’t want to do what he was trying.